# Allign shapefile polygons and underlying image in MATLAB spatial plots?

Tags: shapefile, matlab, matlab-mapping-toolbox

I am plotting a map in MATLAB. For this I have values at corresponding Latitude-Longitude.

I am creating meshgrids for `Lat`, `Lon`, and `values` for plotting the map.

Somehow plotted map does not exactly follow the polygon boundaries whereas polygon boundaries are accurate (*I have verified it)*.

How to resolve this error?

Script and image are shown below, I am using geographic coordinate system.

```
axesm('MapProjection','mercator','AngleUnits', 'degrees');

geoimg = geoshow(lat,lon,data_plot, 'DisplayType', 'texture');
% lat lon, and data_plot are meshgrids
geoimg.AlphaDataMapping = 'none';
geoimg.FaceAlpha = 'texture'; 
alpha(geoimg,double(~isnan(data_plot))) 
colormap('winter');
hold on

shapefile='area.shp'
shape = shaperead(shapefile,  'UseGeoCoords', true);
geoshow(shape, 'FaceAlpha', 0)
```

[image]